# Sending SMS using Java

Tags: java, sms

I am developing a Java web application . I will need to send SMS to a mobile user from the application . How do I achieve this without using a mobile phone for sending SMS?.
I am relatively new to Networks . Please advice .

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22

Comment: [google](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=678&source=hp&q=sending+sms+java+web+application&pbx=1&oq=sending+sms+%2B+java+we&aq=2j&aqi=g-v2g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=c&gs_upl=11043l11782l0l13625l3l3l0l0l0l0l311l633l0.2.0.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=526b4cc9ec6bfa0e) will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the US you could use [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com). It costs 1 cent per SMS and you can send the messages through their REST API. They also have [Java libraries](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java).

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-sms-api/

http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=581

https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+sms&safe=images

Answer (score 0):

You should use SMS gateway. See [here](http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/2997-8-sms-gateways-aggregators) some gateways

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a decision of what protocol has to be used for sms sending? A lot of SMS centers provide REST or SOAP API to send SMS messages. SOAP and REST are much more simpler than SMPP protocol (that is rather low-level) to my mind.

1. If you will decide to use SMPP protocol, there is [SMPPSim](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html) tool which is SMSC (Short Message Service Centre) simulator and allows to test SMS sending functionality in a simple way. So you don't need access to any of real SMSCs.
2. If your SMS provider allows to use SOAP to send SMS messages, you can use [SoapUI Service Mocking](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-soap-services.html) that also allows to develop a client for a SOAP service without access to the real one.

Comment: Thank you all. Let me try SMPPSim as my application is simple one .Il get back if any issue .